# Is it possible to plot 2 graphs in multiplot in gnuplot, with -persist flag?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to do something like that:

gnuplot_script.gp :

```
reset

set term x11 persist
set grid
set size 1,1
set multiplot

i = 0

while (i < 5) {

    set size 0.5,0.5
    set origin 0,0.5

    plot i*sin(x)

    set size 0.5,0.5
    set origin 0.5,0.5

    plot i*cos(x)

    pause 0.5
    i = i + 1
}

unset multiplot
```

I wish to see it animated, but everything just being smeared on the screen...

Is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it...

If you put the "set unset" inside the "while" loop, it works

Comment: what do you actually mean by `set unset`? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It sets and unsets the multiplot mode

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I recall to have read somewhere that Gnuplot "computes" when it encounters a `plot` command but actually draws nothing until the `unset multiplot` (thus explaining why your method is working) , but I can't find my source...